# Qual criptografia o Bitlocker usa?

Tags: windows-10

Qual é o algorítimo utilizado pelo BitLocker no Windows 10? é o AES com chave de 128 bits? Ouvi dizer que ele possui suporte a AES-256 bits, porém não achei nenhum local que me permitisse escolher isso. Eu já até criptografei meu disco externo, mas não sei qual é o algorítimo utilizado.

Answer (score 0):

O BitLocker utiliza o algoritmo XTS-AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) para criptografar os dados. Ele foi instroduzido no Windows 10 (build 1511).

Por padrão a chave é de 128 bits. É possível configurar para 256 bits, no registro do Windows, conforme instruções abaixo:

**HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\FVE**

*Operating System drives: EncryptionMethodWithXtsOs*

*Fixed Data drives: EncryptionMethodWithXtsFdv*

*Removable Data drives: EncryptionMethodWithXtsRdv*

**Valores possíveis:**

- AES-CBC 128bit – value 3
- AES-CBC 128bit – value 4
- AES-XTS 128bit – value 6
- AES-XTS 256bit – value 7

Mais detalhes [aqui](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dubaisec/2016/03/04/bitlocker-aes-xts-new-encryption-type/).